# Get data from AsyncIOMotorCursor python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, python-asyncio

I have someone's code who is not in the company and I want to get the data stored in mongo database which is using AsyncIOMotorClient. I have no experience with motor.

Problem:

I am able to get this:

> AsyncIOMotorCursor(<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7fbd87b45ca0>)

I know how to iterate over <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7fbd87b45ca0>, but when I try to iterate over the above AsyncIOMotorCursor, I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'AsyncIOMotorCursor' object is not iterable

Kindly help.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MOTOR-520

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar is it possible to get only one collection from database? I can use find_one but for that I need to know both key and value. I only know the key. Is there any method to search only using key?

Comment: Update your question with query details.